# how to operate on double-zeroed-indexed array?

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array, vectorization, operation

how to operate on double-zeroed-indexed array?

I.e.

```
sub script        ‘VBA code line
Dim s(), r()      ‘VBA code line
  
s=[{1,2;3,4;5,6}] ‘VBA code line
    
r=sum(application.index(s,0,0), [{7,7;7,7;7,7}])  ‘failed VBA code line
```

`r` is equal to the sum of array `s` and a numerical array, both of size 3 rows by 2 columns, where the latter numerical input array has elements of 7s.

`r` should be equal to this array {[8,9;10,11;12,13]}

What needs to be corrected to make this method work?

I have tried `worksheet(“sheet1”)` before application, and it did not make a difference.

I know of looping, but I want to try for vectorized answer. My background is in MATLAB where vectorizations can be faster than looping. While this may not be true in Excel, I want to pursue vectorization as also the scale of problems of interest are small.

Comment: There is no `sum` in VBA. There is e.g. `Application.Sum` but that still wouldn't work. Could you share the expected result (`r`)?

Comment: Also `s=[{1,2;3,4;5,6}]` returns a base 1 array not base 0

Comment: ... use `Debug.Print LBound(s, 1), UBound(s, 1), LBound(s, 2), UBound(s, 2)` to prove it (`1, 3, 1, 2`).

Comment: `r = Application.Evaluate(s(1, 1) & "+{7,7;7,7;7,7}")`

Comment: I know Matlab calls it index base 1 and Python index base 0, so if that’s what you mean that I want base 1. Is there a reason why I shouldn’t?

Comment: @Vbasic2008 yes I should have put application.sum. But will do

Comment: Based on your edit.  The most likely response is that you will need to use loops.  VBA does not allow the addition of arrays.

Comment: if you were willing to skip the `s` variable you can use: `r = Application.Evaluate("{1,2;3,4;5,6}+{7,7;7,7;7,7}")`  Application Evaluate requires a string to evaluate and will not convert the whole array in `s` to a string that can be used in a worksheet formula.

Comment: or you could do: `r = [{1,2;3,4;5,6}+{7,7;7,7;7,7}]` but that is just shorthand for the application.Evaluate when not using variables.

Comment: You say _My background is in MATLAB where vectorizations can be faster than looping_.  well, VBA does not directly support vector math.  While Excel formulas do have some support for vector math, calling Excel will often (but not always) be slower.  Even if you find a Excel formula solution,  I'd advise thoroughly testing its performance vs an optimised vba looping solution.

Comment: Another approach might be an [xll addin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/make-custom-functions-compatible-with-xll-udf) which you could write or potentially buy.

Answer (score 0):

### Sum Up Same-Sized Arrays

**Usage**

```vb
Sub SumDataTest()

    Dim s() As Variant, r() As Variant
    
    s = [{1,2;3,4;5,6}]
    'PrintData s

    r = SumData(s, [{7,7;7,7;7,7}])
    'PrintData r

End Sub
```

**The Function**

```vb
Function SumData(ByVal Data1 As Variant, ByVal Data2 As Variant) As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = LBound(Data1, 1) To UBound(Data1, 1)
        For c = LBound(Data1, 2) To UBound(Data1, 2)
            Data1(r, c) = Data1(r, c) + Data2(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    SumData = Data1
End Function
```

**PrintData Result**

```
s
1 2
3 4
5 6
r
 8  9
10 11
12 13
```

- You can find the `PrintData` procedure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75007333).

Comment: Thanks - it helps. Do you recommend any sites/ git places that have pre-built functions like this ready for matrix operations? I can know this function will be very common, but there many more common operations that will need to be set up.

Comment: The only thing I stumbled upon is [Cristian Buse - VBA-ArrayTools](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-ArrayTools).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vba array and want to perform array operation with `Evaluate` you should convert it to text. In new version of Excel you can use `ArrayToText` function:

```
Sub script()
   Dim s(), r()
   s = [{1,2;3,4;5,6}]
   r = Evaluate(WorksheetFunction.ArrayToText(s, 1) & "+{7,7;7,7;7,7}")
  ' Debug.Print r(2, 2)   ' prints 11
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - I did see cstr() but that wouldn’t covert my array for the application.evaluate. I’ll try this.